# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python

> I am trying to read a txt file into python and getting the above error. I want to convert each line into 3 columns. 
>   The text file looks like this -

```
1714,Sales,Math
10070,Research,Science
1704,Developer,History
32696,QA,Math
16421,Marketing,Science
25925,Sales,History
```

My code looks like this :

```
    import pandas as pd 
a=open('/Users/mezbahuddin/Downloads/dept_course.txt')
b=a.read()
for line in b:
    g,h,i=line.strip().split(",",2)
    print(g[0],h[0],i[0])
```

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you searched this site for a similar error message? Have you tried printing out intermediate values to validate that your assumptions are correct?

Comment: Look closer at this line `g,h,i=line.strip().split(",",2)`. What will `strip().split(',', 2)` return? Also saying `a=b.read()` is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did. None of the posts provided a clear solution.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry thanks, I now see what you were mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

```
b=a.read()
for line in b:
```

`b` isn't a collection of lines. `b` is a single string. `for line in b:` will cause `line` to iterate through `b` character-by-character.

To iterate through the file line-by-line, do `for line in a:`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The following code now works for me :                          
a=open('/~dept_course.txt')
b=a.readlines()
for line in a:
    g,h,i=line.strip().split(",",2)